# Security of in-house data storage vs. cloud storage

Tags: cloud-storage

What factors should be considered in comparing corporate in-house data storage on internet-connected systems vs. 3rd party cloud storage solutions? Are the latter worthy of consideration where budget is limited?

Encryption would be used for local storage or on top of whatever the cloud storage facility provides.

It is assumed that the data is fairly voluminous (hundreds of TB in multi-GB chunks). It is valuable (think of maybe $100m) commercially and to various governments (but not particularly to hackers), and needs to be accessed from a few different locations.

Comment: What do you mean by the "budget is limited"? Especially with the estimated value of the stored data it is hard to get an idea of that limit.

Comment: @TomK. Something of the order of a full-time job for a good security professional would be acceptable, but not armed 24/7 guards and that sort of thing, and probably no air gap to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the actual threats and the relative importance of the 3 pilars of data security: Confidentiality, Integrity, Availability.

But here are some pros and cons:

Cost: you are changing buying for renting. Depending on your economic model, and cash flow, one may be more interesting than the other, or may be a mix...

Availability: local storage will require backups, and the company will have to setup and run backup procedures and recovery tests. You should considere the Mean Time Between Failure of the storage system, and the Maximum Tolerable Period of Disruption in your recovery procedures. All that comes out of the box with a cloud solution - provide you choose a serious provider.

Confidentiality/Integrity: if someone can enter in your internal systems, he will be able to access to your data be it local of in the cloud. But **You** cannot be sure of who really can access data when it resides in a cloud. So a cloud solution will add risks here. Whether they can be accepted depends of the sensitiveness of the data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the impression for an internet-connected system that you cannot be 100% sure of who accesses it anyhow, so the difference between those two risk factors is what I'm interested in exploring.If a government is interested in helping their corporations they could exploit weaknesses, but the $ amounts are not all that big for that to happen.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Not exactly. An european company that stores its sensitive data in a North American cloud has a much more exposure to attacks from American companies than if data lies in private storage. Not speaking of govermental agencies...